# DISTINCT combined with CONCAT() not working

Tags: mysql, concatenation, distinct

I am unable to resolve this issue. The 1st query below works and returns distinct values for the **name** column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name
FROM products AS p
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

The 2nd query stops filtering DISTINCT values for **name** - when I use CONCAT() to return an sku:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name, CONCAT('B', p.id) AS sku
FROM products AS p
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

**EDIT**

Here is some sample data to test:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (1, 'Truck');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (2, 'Truck');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (3, 'Truck');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (4, 'Car');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (5, 'Car');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (6, 'Car');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (7, 'Bike');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (8, 'Plane');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (9, 'Train');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (10, 'Canoe');
```

It seems like a simple enough problem, but I am unable to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: I've edited and submitted sample data above for you to test. Thanks.

Comment: Since id is unique, adding it to select means every row is returned. Do you mean group_concat with a group by instead of just concat?

Comment: Please also include the output you want based on this sample data.

Comment: Only the name needs to be unique. I need to return the concated sku with the query (example B1, B4, B7, B8 etc) with no duplicate names. I may be using an incorrect function or my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY RAND()) rn
    FROM products
)

SELECT id, name
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY RAND()  -- or whatever order you want here
LIMIT 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `DISTINCT` you can group by name and return the min `id` of each name:

```
SELECT name, CONCAT('B', MIN(id)) AS sku
FROM products 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d50fb4198157cd76c98d91b71301a5fc).